# How do I disable join/leave messages in Slack?

Tags: notifications, slack

Slack insists on telling me that

```
foo: joined #best-chat-room-yay
```

Is there a way to disable this?

Comment: I added an answer, but I'm curious if you ever found anything else related to the topic? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UPDATE: [It seems it's now possible](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/133106/78014)

Not as it is at the moment, no, unfortunately.

One thing you can do, is to mute the channel.

[image: notification preferences menu]

If that is not an option, then you're out of luck. The last thing I heard about this was in august 2015, where [this tweet](https://twitter.com/SlackHQ/status/634518770493603841) was made by Slack on Twitter:

> @SlackHQ: can we hide join/leave messages through global or channel
>   settings?
>
> @willimac not at the moment but we're glad to send your
>   request over to our team!

I myself have been using [this userstyle](https://userstyles.org/styles/106647/wordpress-slack-hide-join-leave) as I'm only using Slack for WordPress: https://userstyles.org/styles/106647/wordpress-slack-hide-join-leave. I don't know if this is something you will be able to modify or user for other use cases.

WordPress also [links to this](https://make.wordpress.org/chat/) at their official page about Slack, so I'm guessing that there isn't an official solution out there yet :/

Comment: Just in case anyone comes across answer like I did - it's been possible for a while now - https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/133106/193667

Answer (score 4):

This has been possible for a while now: https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/115002695043-Manage-join-and-leave-messages-

1. From your desktop, click your workspace name in the top left.
2. Select Administration, then Workspace settings from the menu. *
3. Scroll down to the Join & Leave Messages section and click Expand.
4. Check or uncheck the box next to Show a message when people join or leave channels.
5. Click Save

* only available to the administrators of the Workspace

Answer (score 2):

You could open the dev tools (hit F12) and run this on the console:

```
setInterval(function(){ $('.message.joined').hide(); }, 1000);
```

This will hide the "joined" messages within 1 second after they appear.  You could even create a bookmarklet with this code so all you have to do is click your bookmarklet to start the interval.

Yes it's hacky, but it should do the job until they add the option in the preferences.